# Multiple character replacement in R

Tags: r

Below is the part of my code and as you can see, I am trying to remove string of characters and some meta characters. Is there a way I could do this replacements in just one line? I tried by writing the symbols for open and close parethesis after the word function but it does not work.

```
{

    P1 <- gsub("function", "", deparse(s)[1]);            #removing the word "function"
    P2 <- gsub("\\(", "", P1);                            #removing open parenthesis
    P3 <- gsub("\\)", "", P2);                            #removing the close parenthesis
    P4 <- gsub("\\s", "", P3);                            #removing spaces
    variables <- strsplit(P4,",");                        #separating the variables

}
```

Comment: Could you make this into a reproducible example? You could `dput()` your data.

Answer (score 0):

`gsub` can take regular expressions. So you could write something like:

```
x <- "some_func function()"
gsub("function|\\s|\\(|\\)", "", x)

[1] "some_func"
```

Or if you have a vector of things to remove:

```
to_remove <- c("function", "\\s", "\\(", "\\)")
gsub(paste(to_remove, collapse = "|"), "", x)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not one line solution but you can simplify the code like this:

```
listToReplace <- c("function", "\\(", "\\s")

string <- "function.... ...BBB((BBBB"

gsub(paste(listToReplace,collapse="|"), "",     string)
```